# My website takes a long time to START loading

Tags: performance

My website takes a long time to start loading.  Once it starts there's a 3 second load time which is fine, but it seems to do nothing for 7 seconds first.

Can anyone help me to understand what those 7 seconds are, and how I might reduce that period of time.

Here's a picture of my load times to help you understand what I mean.

https://www.squareballoon.co.uk/downloads/stackoverflow/load-times.png

Comment: From the headers on your site I would say: Try and disable some of those cPanel modules if you don't need them

Comment: X-site duplicate: [How to reduce the “Time for the first byte” on my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8539784/761202)